# Using callback function instead of state when changing state's value in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why we need to use callback function instead of state value in react when setting state to the new value?

Comment: Do you mean https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback function should be used if you are relying on previous state,
for example: setState(prevState => prevState + 5)

You have to do it this way because React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance. It means that the value that you get from state directly might not be updated yet, so you will run into a bug. But the state value that you get as a parameter in setState callback is always correct.
It is described very well here in react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous